# pip install pillow doesn't work on windows 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-imaging-library, windows-11

I am trying to use the pillow package but it doesn't want to install. It works on my windows 10 machine, but I need it to work on my other machine, which is windows 11, as well. My pip version is the same on both machines: 22.2.2 and I tried upgrading pip, it doesn't help. I tried reinstalling python but noticed something weird. When I type `python --version`, my current python version is 3.8.7 and I don't know why. I uninstalled python via controll panel, there is no python visible in the list in controll panel anymore, where does this python come from and how do I get rid of it so that I can use python 3.10? And will this also solve the problem of not being able to install pipllow. This is the full error message I recieve when trying `python -m pip install pillow`

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages)
Collecting pillow
  Using cached Pillow-9.2.0.tar.gz (50.0 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pillow
  Building wheel for pillow (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [181 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.mingw-3.8
      creating build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FitsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_deprecate.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      running egg_info
      writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src\Pillow.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.c'
      warning: no files found matching '*.h'
      warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
      warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext


      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\sofie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-43p29232\pillow_96fe495f59934c0c8237da68ac991778\setup.py", line 995, in <module>
          setup(
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 155, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 79, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "C:\Users\sofie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-43p29232\pillow_96fe495f59934c0c8237da68ac991778\setup.py", line 810, in build_extensions
          raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
      __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\sofie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-43p29232\pillow_96fe495f59934c0c8237da68ac991778\setup.py", line 1015, in <module>
          raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
      __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow
  Running setup.py clean for pillow
Failed to build pillow
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages)
Installing collected packages: pillow
  Running setup.py install for pillow ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pillow did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [185 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.mingw-3.8
      creating build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FitsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_deprecate.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\PIL
      running egg_info
      writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src\Pillow.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.c'
      warning: no files found matching '*.h'
      warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
      warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext


      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\sofie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-43p29232\pillow_96fe495f59934c0c8237da68ac991778\setup.py", line 995, in <module>
          setup(
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 155, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 68, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\install.py", line 670, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 79, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "C:\Users\sofie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-43p29232\pillow_96fe495f59934c0c8237da68ac991778\setup.py", line 810, in build_extensions
          raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
      __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\sofie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-43p29232\pillow_96fe495f59934c0c8237da68ac991778\setup.py", line 1015, in <module>
          raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
      __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pillow

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages)
```

Comment: Adding --prefer-binary to pip install might help. Reason for the failure seems to be that pillow requires zlib headers during the compilation (as pillow is not pure python) and you dont have those. However, pillow does ship with wheels (already compiled binaries) but it looks like your pip will default to installing from source..

Comment: pip install --prefer-binary pillow

Comment: You can see in the error message that python is located at `c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8`, so it is part of MinGW. You need to install a new Python 3.10 and then make sure that the `%PATH%` environment variable in Windows contains `C:\Program Files\Python310` and 
`C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts` (or whereever you installed it) and that those entries are above/before the MinGW path. That will make sure that when you run `python` in the terminal, it will use the new python and not the MinGW python

Comment: @rasjani you literally saved my day after 2 hours of frustration 

Answer (score 0):

Though I have never encountered this problem, but from the error messages, I am guessing it's a problem with missing modules.

```
__main__.RequiredDependencyException:

      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
```

Try run `import zlib`, see if there is any errors importing the module. Install `zlib` if you don't have it yet.

---

Also, there is an [issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4242) on the Pillow repo on GitHub reporting the same problem. According to that, you can also try re-install `pip` see if that solves the problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the respose, I had zlib and I already read the issue on GitHub reporting the same problem and tried those solutions. In the end I found the python 3.8 on py pc, deleted it, installed python 3.10 and it just worked, I have no idea why, but my problem is solved, thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

see that

i just solve it now , it take me alot of time

i had error when import matplotlib

first cut or delete or uninstall PIL. i delete it
and then
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
or pip install --upgrade Pillow
or see in web to find version